# For Direct-Sequence Spread Spectrum, can we reduce the transmit power of the signal to maintain a fixed BER?

Tags: digital-communications

How to reduce the transmit power of the signal to maintain a fixed BER in CDMA ? I am thinking noise power spectral density, signal energy , and signal rate.

Comment: The difficulty is that the transmitter would need to know the received signal power, requiring a feedback channel that is not always available and is itself subject to errors.

Comment: Let's say we have a feedback channel with gives us RSSI output in that case how would we control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BER depends on your E_b/N0. You need to keep that constant if you want constant BER.

Now, you don't say *how* your comparing your DSSS system, but it would make sense to assume that your symbol rate constant, thereby increasing your bandwidth by the spreading factor, and keeping the duration of a symbol constant.

In that case, Energy is still the product of power and duration, and the latter stayed constant.